# Restore List item to the older version using CSOM C# approach

Tags: csom, versioning, list-item, version-history

we need to restore list items from a particular list (not document library) to the older version

but what i can understand is for document libraries we do have that provision like

```
Item.File.Versions.RestoreByLabel(VersionLabel)
```

The similar kind of method does not exist in the

> microsoft.sharepoint.client.ListItem

namespace

we can just perform something like below

```
Item.Versions
```

there is no method to restore item by restoreby label

how exactly we need to restore list items..

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Hi, DId you resolved this? Please let me know if you have an answer for this?